# In R, how do I combine a colonial dyad network and a contiguity network and then find the shortest paths between two nodes in the combined network?

Tags: r, network-analysis

I'm trying to use the Correlates of War Direct Contiguity data to find the number of contiguous links between colonial dyads, which is a separate dataset and network (Harvard Business School Spread of Imperialism). I can create the networks separately using the network() function, or igraph's graph_from_adjacency_matrix on matrices that I've created for both datasets. However, I can't figure out how to map the colonial dyads onto the contiguity network to find the contiguous distance between colonial dyads.

[Colonial Dyads data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Vny.png)
[Contiguity data filtered for 2016 only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kedh6.png)

I tried using igraph's union function, but when I apply the distances() function to sum the contiguous links, each of which has a value of 1-5 according the contiguity dataset, the numbers look way too small. Also, I'm not sure how to isolate the colonial dyads so that I can find the number of links between them.[image of the network after union()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ogak.png).

```
## Colonial dyad matrix
col_dyad <- read.csv("colonial_dyads.csv")


states <-unique(c(as.character(col_dyad$Empire),as.character(col_dyad$Country)))


col_mat <- matrix(0,nrow=length(states),ncol=length(states)) # 
    rownames(col_mat) <-     states
        colnames(col_mat) <-     states
for(i in 1:dim(col_dyad)[1]){
    col_mat[as.character(col_dyad$Empire[i]),as.character(col_dyad$Country[i])] <- col_mat[as.character(col_dyad$Empire[i]),as.character(col_dyad$Country[i])]+1
}

# Colonial dyad network using igraph

col_net1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(col_mat)
```

```
# Contiguity matrix
cont <- read.csv("contdird.csv")
cont <-  unique(cont[,c("state1ab","state2ab","conttype","year")])

cont <- filter(cont, year == 2016)


cont_states <- unique(c(as.character(conttype_data$state1ab),as.character(conttype_data$state2ab)))

## Creates square matrix
cont_mat <- matrix(0, nrow = length(cont_states), ncol = length(cont_states))
rownames(cont_mat) <-     cont_states
        colnames(cont_mat) <-     cont_states
        
        dim(cont_mat)
        

conttype_data <- cont %>% uncount(cont$conttype)

##Fills in matrix with uncounted data

for(i in 1:dim(conttype_data)[1]){
cont_mat[as.character(conttype_data$state1ab[i]),as.character(conttype_data$state2ab[i])] <- cont_mat[as.character(conttype_data$state1ab[i]),as.character(conttype_data$state2ab[i])]+1

}

# Contiguity network igraph
cont_net1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(cont_mat)

# union graph
col_cont_net <- union(col_net1, cont_net1)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.